# Mute/stop video running in background (Delphi - Android App)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have an application in Delphi that plays video. When I open another application, but blank the screen, I hear the Video sound all the time.
How can I detect that the screen has been blanked, or there has been a switch to another application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
uses FMX.Platform;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
AppEventSvc:IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService,IInterface(AppEventSvc)) then
begin
AppEventSvc.SetApplicationEventHandler(AppEvent);
end;
end;

function TMyForm.AppEvent(AAppEvent:TApplicationEvent;AContext:TObject):Boolean;
begin
if AAppEvent=TApplicationEvent.WillTerminate then
begin
// Do soomething
end;
Result:=True;
end;
```